# Auto-generate Grails domains based on Database Schema?

Tags: grails

Is there an app or a script that is available that will allow me to auto generate grails domain classes based on the tables in an existing database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it... Grails Application Generator available on sourceforge.  http://sourceforge.net/projects/grag/